# Error in x/x.expected:non-conformable arrays

Tags: r

```
# rm(list=ls(all=T))

# Create matrix and specify dimensions, and name each 
variable
Sdata =  

matrix(c(417.38,91.62,231.54,222.46,209.84,278.16,315.12,492.88) 
, nrow = 2, ncol = 4)
rownames(Sdata)= c("No myocardial infraction", "Myocardial 
Infraction")
colnames(Sdata)= c("No vessel disease", "Sinlge-vessel 
disease","Double-vessel disease","Triple-vessel disease")

Sdata
# specify g-test parameters
g.test.contingency = function(x, print = T) {
  row.sum = apply(x,1,sum)
  col.sum = apply(x,1,sum)
  #sum of all the elements (n)
  n = sum(x)
  x.expected = row.sum %o% col.sum / n
  g = 2*sum(x*log(x/x.expected))
  degf = (nrow(x) - 1) * (ncol(x)-1)
  p.g = 1 - pchisq(g,degf)
  if (print) {
  cat("G-Test for Contingency Tables\n\n")
  cat("Data:\n")
  print(x)
  cat("\n")
  cat("The test statistic is ", signif(g,6),".\n")
  cat("There are ", degf, "degrees of freedom.\n")
  cat("The p-value is ",p.g,".\n\n\n")
}
  return(invisible(list(expected = x.expected,test.stat = g, 
p.value = p.g)))
    }

g.test.contingency(Sdata)
```

This is the R code that I have written, however, I am unable to get R to run the contingency analysis because of the error you can see at the bottom. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake / typo: `col.sum = apply(x,2,sum)`.

Comment: Been starring at this program too long, thank you so much!!